# Linux USB Not Recognized: device descriptor read/64, error -71

Tags: boot, usb, dmesg

I have a USB (SanDisk's Ultra Fit), which has Ubuntu installed in it. It was functioning perfectly well until it suddenly shutdown for no apparent reason. After that, my PC's BIOS won't recognize my USB. Both Windows and Linux barely react when the corrupt USB is plugged in. `lsusb` and `fdisk` do not list the USB, and `dmesg` looks like this.

```
[ 109.633643] usb 1-1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 114.738034] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 130.354518] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 130.542526] usb 1-1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 130.634561] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 130.834550] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 131.026476] usb 1-1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 131.450568] usb 1-1.1: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[ 131.530519] usb 1-1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 131.954506] usb 1-1.1: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[ 131.956086] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 131.956809] scsi 4:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 131.956814] scsi 4:0:0:0: killing request
[ 131.958538] sdg: detected capacity change from 250450280448 to 0
[ 132.078530] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 132.170541] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 132.370575] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 132.558608] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 132.650571] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 132.850501] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 132.958700] usb 1-1-port1: attempt power cycle
[ 133.562577] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 133.982537] usb 1-1.1: device not accepting address 8, error -71
[ 134.066760] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[ 134.494561] usb 1-1.1: device not accepting address 9, error -71
[ 134.494875] usb 1-1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

If possible, I would like to completely recover my USB. If that's impossible, I would like to wipe my USB and reinstall Ubuntu, which I also cannot do because the USB isn't recognized by programs such as GParted.

Any help on either two requests will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If no longer recognized then replace it.

Comment: Hello. If it makes you feel better how old is it? If it has a problem once why would you even think about trying to reinstalling Ubuntu on it?

Comment: I thought that if the problem was caused purely by "software problems" and not "hardware problems", reinstalling Ubuntu would renew the USB.